# List in note block Obsidian

Tags: markdown, obsidian, obsidian-dataview

I wonder if its possible to create list in Obsidian note block this way

>[!note]- Annotation

> list should begin here

I tried starting list with '- ' syntax but it did no effect. Please help me to find out how it should be done.

[image]

Comment: To clarify your question, could you include a screen shot of the desired result?

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me

```
>[!note] Annotation
> - Item 1
> - Item 2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice work-around for the problem. Using the `Search & Replace in Current File` in Obsidian, you can find the bullet points (`-`) you need to convert, and then replace it with the block-quotes (`> -`)

([Click here to Preview of the Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nk3k.png))

Here are the steps:

- Open your Command Palette using `Ctrl+P` (or the hotkeys you have set for command pallete)
- search for `Search & Replace in Current File`
- Use the following as your search and replacement query
  ([see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0jvM.png))

  - Search (which is the first field) : `-`
  - Replace (which is the second field): `> -`
- Use the *Next*, *Prev*, and other buttons to navigate to your desired list.
- Choose `Replace` or `Replace All` to convert the bullet points into block quotes

And there you go! With some little cleaning at the end, you will have all the list elements inside the callouts